# Every 4th Monday?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

Is there any way I can set up Google Calendar to remind me to pay rent

**every 4th Monday** (= every 28 days)?

Not *monthly and every 4th Monday*. 
That's why I missed my last payment ....

Comment: Question is ambiguous. Do you want it to remind you every 4 weeks on a Monday?

Comment: every 4th Monday = every 4th week = every 28 days. I need to be more specific next time ...

Comment: Great, then **Every four weeks on Monday** option from Alex will do the trick

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Every fourth Monday of each month:**

1. Choose the 4th Monday of a month and set a new event there.
2. Set the repeats to **Monthly**
3. Set Repeat every: **1 months**
4. Set Repeat by: **day of the week**

The calendar will show you **Summary:   Monthly on the fourth Monday**

The first step is very important since it will be the starting point and the event will repeat according to that particular day.

**Every four weeks on Monday**

1. Set the repeats to **Weekly**
2. Set Repeat every: **4 weeks**
3. Set Repeat on: **Monday**

Comment: I want the event to repeat `every 4th Monday` not every 4th Monday of a month....

Comment: See my edit. I've added the other option as well.

Comment: thank you. I was after the second option. Not sure why it didn't come to me and I had to ask...